# SSRS Preserve blank sheet when report is exported to Excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that runs fine and I need to export to Excel. My report is exported with multiple sheets in Excel.

I have one tablix which groups by my parent fields
and every time I export in Excel the export is ok.

But the problem is if I have no data the sheets, then in excel it will not display. How do I handle this problem: even if there's no data in the field that group by the Excel page name should appear.

Comment: Ow Im shocked No one answered my question

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with one of my reports and what I found is that if no rows are returned within the group, the sheet is not generated (exactly as you found). The fix I found was to create a single row at either the top or bottom of the group that will appear only when there are no other records in the group. This way, there will always be at least one row rendered in each group. This row can contain a text string, such as a message like "There are no records that match this criteria!".

Once you have set up the row as you see fit, change the visibility of the added row to only show up when there are no rows in the group. This can be done several ways, depending on how you are grouping the data for each group. For instance, if your grouping expression is ParentID, then you would set the visibility of the added row to

```
=IIF(CountRows(Fields!ParentID.Value)>0,true,false)
```

In case you're not familiar with hidden expressions, you ***do not*** encase the true and false in quotes. If you do, it will throw an error.

This way, you will always render at least one row, and thus each group will always have a sheet generated!

Hope this helps.